# Puting a ModalPopupExtender on Master Page then displaying popup on content page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a a Panel with an ajax ModalPupupExtender on my master page that I would like to be able to display on all my content pages.  When all the relevant code is on a content page, everything works fine.  When I move the markup and code behind to the master page, my popup doesn't popup.  Hear's some code:

#### Markup on master page:

```
...
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
...ext...

<%-- invisible button for TargetControlID property --%>

        <asp:Button Style="display:none" ID="UselessButton" runat="server" Text="I am useless"/>

<%-- popup --%>

        <asp:Panel style="width: 500px; display: none" ID="WarningMessageBoxPanel" runat="server" CssClass="popup">

            <asp:Panel runat="Server" ID="WarningPopupDragHandle" CssClass="popupDragHandle">
                <asp:Image ID="WariningIcon1" runat="server" CssClass="centerImage" ImageUrl="~/Images/messageBox_ExclamationMark.jpg" />
            </asp:Panel>
            <br />
            <div class=" warningDiv requiredMedium">
                <asp:Label ID="WarningMessage" runat="server" Text="placeholder message"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
                <asp:Button ID="OKButton" runat="server" Text="OK"/>
            </div>

        </asp:Panel>

        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="WarningMessageBoxPopupExtender" runat="server" 
            BehaviorID="WarningMessageBoxPopupExtender" TargetControlID="UselessButton" 
            PopupControlID="WarningMessageBoxPanel" OkControlID="OKButton" DropShadow="true" Drag="true" 
            PopupDragHandleControlID="WarningPopupDragHandle">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Code behind on master page

```
public void ShowWarningBox(String message)
{
    WarningMessage.Text = message;
    WarningMessageBoxPopupExtender.Show();

}//end ShowWarningBox()
```

On the content page I have the fallowing heading near the top of the markup:

`<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Site.Master" %>`

I should then be able to call `showWarningBox()` from any content page that has the aforementioned heading with the command `Master.ShowWarningBox()`.  The function is calling, but the popup just isn't displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Site siteObj = this.Master as Site;
```